# Place a image relative to iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, resolution

In my app there is a feature where you can drag and drop a image ,image is in a `UIimageView`. Its a universal app.I need to store the x,y coordinates relative to **2048x1536** .I use `CGPointApplyAffineTransform` to calculate the relative point .And inverse the transform to iPhone screen to find the relative position on iPhone screen. Due to pixel density variation i am not getting the relative position correctly.

```
CGFloat TARGET_WIDTH  =2048.00;
CGFloat TARGET_HEIGHT =1536.00;



CGPoint thispoint=    CGPointApplyAffineTransform(imageView.frame.origin, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(TARGET_HEIGHT/self.view.frame.size.height, TARGET_WIDTH/self.view.frame.size.width));
```

This is the code i find the relative point .

And i inverse the transform with iPhone view size how do i calculate the relative with the density of pixels iPad and iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Test this,

```
CGFloat TARGET_WIDTH  =2048.00;
CGFloat TARGET_HEIGHT =1536.00;
CGFloat xScaleFactor = TARGET_WIDTH / self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat yScaleFactor = TARGET_HEIGHT / self.view.frame.size.height;
CGPoint thispoint = CGPointMake(imageView.frame.origin.x*xScaleFactor, imageView.frame.origin.y*yScaleFactor); 
//point with respect to your given target size
```